# Cmake won't find correct version of Boost

Tags: boost, cmake

I am trying to build some code using cmake. The code uses some Boost libraries. Because of that I try to find Boost in the cmakefile:

```
find_package(Boost 1.65.1 REQUIRED COMPONENTS unit_test_framework program_options )
```

I have installed boost version 1.58 via apt (I am using Linux Mint 18.3), so I obviously get the error message when trying to cmake the code:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1677 (message):
Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

Boost version: 1.58.0

Boost include path: /usr/include

Detected version of Boost is too old.  Requested version was 1.65.1 (or newer).
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

So I went on and downloaded Boost 1.65.1 by source and built it the intended way and installed it with the prefix

```
sudo ./b2 install --prefix=/usr/include
```

When I try to build the code again, it still gives the exact same error message as before, stating that it didn't find the newer version. I have tried to uninstall version 1.58 and build, but then cmake doesn't find Boost at all.

How can I install Boost in a way, that cmake is able to find it?

Thanks in advance,
cheers!

Comment: Did you clear the CMakeCache.txt after the changes? You need to do so.

Comment: Wow, that actually was the problem, thanks a lot. Should I add this to the original question or post it as an answer or anything like that?

Comment: I'll come up with an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When changing the version information of Boost in a `find_package(Boost)` call you need to clear the `CMakeCache.txt` file. Otherwise the cached information from the previous run is used.